# Selenium in python is giving error

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

[image][image]i have written a code in selenium using chrome driver, it codes works fine on some days and some days it gives error.Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


import os
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/searchlist')

# try:
#     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
#         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Promoter"))
#     )
# finally:
#     print('0000000000000000000000')
#     driver.quit()

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('Promoter').click()

divisionLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Division')).options)
print('*********{}'.format(divisionLength))

firstRow = 0
titleRow = []
contentRows = []

gdistName = ""
gdivName  = ""

for divisionElement in range(1,divisionLength):
    selectDivision = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Division'))
    selectDivision.options
    selectDivision.select_by_index(divisionElement)
    time.sleep(1)
    districtLength = 
len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District')).options)
    gdivName =  (selectDivision.options)[divisionElement].text
    while districtLength == 1:
        print("43")
    print(districtLength)
    for districtElement in range(1,districtLength):
        selectDistrict = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District'))
        selectDistrict.options

        selectDistrict.select_by_index(districtElement)
        gdistName =  (selectDistrict.options)[districtElement].text

        time.sleep(2)
        projectLength = 
len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project')).options)

        print('/------------------------------/')
        print('/-----project number: {}-------/'.format(projectLength))
        print('/------------------------------/')
        if projectLength == 1:
            continue

        for projectElement in range(1,projectLength):
            selectDistrict = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District'))
            selectDistrict.select_by_index(0)
            selectDistrict.select_by_index(districtElement)
            time.sleep(2)
            gdistName =  (selectDistrict.options)[districtElement].text
            # selectProject.options

            # while len(selectProject.options) == 1:
            #     print(len(selectProject.options))
            #     print("65")
            # c = len(select.options)
            # print('---------------{}'.format(c))

            # titleRow = []
            # contentRows = []
            # firstRow = 0

            # for i in range(1,c):
            #     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project'))
            #     while len(select.options) == 1:
            #         pass
            selectProject = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project'))
            time.sleep(2)
            selectProject.select_by_index(projectElement)

            driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
            tableRows = 
driver.find_element_by_class_name('table').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

            if firstRow == 0:
                headRow = tableRows[0].find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
                for headRowData in range(0,len(headRow)):
                    text = 
headRow[headRowData].find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
                    titleRow.append(text)
                firstRow = firstRow + 1

            for dataRowsNumbers in range(1,len(tableRows)):
                dataRow = 
tableRows[dataRowsNumbers].find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                tempList = []
                for dataRowContents in range(0,len(dataRow)):
                    try:
                        a_link = 
dataRow[dataRowContents].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                        tempList.append(str(a_link))
                    except NoSuchElementException:

                        tempList.append(str(dataRow[dataRowContents].text))
                    # if dataRow[dataRowContents].text == 'View':
                    #     a_link = 
dataRow[dataRowContents].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                    #     tempList.append(str(a_link))
                    # else:
                    #     
tempList.append(str(dataRow[dataRowContents].text))
                    #print(dataRow[dataRowContents].text)
                tempList.append(gdivName)
                tempList.append(gdistName)
                print(tempList)
                contentRows.append(tempList)
# print('Automated check is over')
# print('Stored data in programs is as below:')
# print(contentRows)
with open("./data.csv",'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvfile.writerow(titleRow)
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0,len(contentRows)):
        csvfile.writerow(contentRows[i])

driver.close()
```

Please excuse of intended spaces.

so i receive this error when i run it..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\Crawlers\Maha_Rera1.py", line 68, in 
<module>
    selectDistrict.select_by_index(districtElement)
  File 
"C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 103, in select_by_index
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % 
index)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate 
element with index 2
```

Please , if someone can suggest me what to change , because it worked fine yesterday and not it is not working..It requires chrome driver to run

this is the website: https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/searchlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using select.select_by_value(districtElement) instead of index

Comment: convert to string select.select_by_value(str(districtElement))